# .net core authentication with google with remote membership storage

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core

I am implementing an application using microservices approach.
On my application there must be Google sign-in and basic sign-in.
I have 2 services: 1 for membership service and 1 for MVC gateway.
My membership service has db and standard asp.net core identity applied. So all users stored here.
My MVC gateway has login action that needs to challenge Google and get external login. And then get a user from Membership service for this login.

First my idea was to implement custom `IUserStore` class and call restful Api methods from Membership service. But there I faced the problem with syncing 2 Identities - on both services. Then I removed Identity from MVC Gateway, but now I cannot challenge Google Sign-in.

[image: Auth process]

So what is the best solution for such approach?
I saw in MS example that there was IdentityServerr4 used, but I don't think that this is viable for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented using IdentityServer4.