# .net core send ClaimsPrincipal as a response of an action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient, claims-based-identity

I am trying to pass User data as `ClaimsPrincipal` from one API service to another.

```
[HttpPost("getexternal")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUserByExternalLogin(ExternalSignModel model, [FromServices]IEnumerable<IExternalAuthentication> providers, [FromServices]IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<MembershipUser> claimsPrincipalFactory)
{
    if (model == null) return BadRequest("Missing agrumets");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Code)) return BadRequest($"{nameof(model.Code)} must not be empty");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Provider)) return BadRequest($"{nameof(model.Provider)} must not be empty");

    var provider = providers.FirstOrDefault(w => w.ProviderName == model.Provider);

    if (provider == null) return BadRequest($"Provider for external login {model.Provider} is missing");
    try
    {
        var externalLoginInfo = await provider.AuthenticateAsync(model.Code);
        var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(externalLoginInfo.LoginProvider,
            externalLoginInfo.ProviderKey);
        user = user ?? await _membershipUserHandler.RegisterUser(externalLoginInfo);
        var claimsPrincipal = await claimsPrincipalFactory.CreateAsync(user);
        return Ok(claimsPrincipal);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

And here is the caller service:

```
public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> GetUserByExternalLogin(ExternalSignModel model)
{
    var uri = $"{BaseServiceUri}/getexternal";
    var response = await _client.PostAsync(uri, model, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    var user = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ClaimsPrincipal>();

    return user;
}
```

`_client` is just a `HttpClient`

but when I do `return Ok(claimsPrincipal);` on the caller I get 400 error.

What do I do wrong? How can I send ClaimsPrincipal?

Comment: That's not really how this sort of thing works. Most likely, you're looking for something like IdentityServer. There's a *flow* to this. You authenticate with the provider (IdentityServer) and it returns a token that contains the claims. The auth framework in ASP.NET Core, for example, will then use that to build a `ClaimsPrincipal` and set all the stuff like `HttpContext.User`, etc.

Comment: @ChrisPratt well yeah it looks like IdentityServer, but it is a little bit not like this, or may be I don't understand.
Here I asked a question of how to do better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224665/net-core-authentication-with-google-with-remote-membership-storage
so my structure is described on chart, but very cut.

Comment: An alternative might be to create a JWT and send that through as a string. Then, instead of trying to deserialize into a ClaimsPrincipal, simply decode the JWT which will actually return a ClaimsPrincipal

Comment: @ChrisPratt, I was thinking about this, but doesn't it mean that I will need the same coding/decoding key in both services?

Comment: Yes, but you'd want that either way. Definitely don't want to be sending claims over the wire unencrypted, no matter which path you choose.

Comment: Again, that's where an actual provider like IdentityServer comes into play. The app itself auths, and thereby gets the creds it needs to decrypt what the provider sends back. You're essentially trying to roll your own system here and encountering all the headaches existing solutions have already solved for you.

Comment: @ChrisPratt what I was thinking why not to use IdentityServer is that I need to sign in with google on my SPA and then send google Identity (auth code or token itself) to gateway, and then somehow pass that Identity to IdentityServer. So in other words how do I need to use that google sign-in with Identity server?
I take auth code pass it to IdentityServer, validate google auth code, then register/obtain user, and then get the token that IdentitySever produce?